# How to get the index of element in the List<T> in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list who have some element like  A  B  C  D.
I want to get the index of  B.
How i can get it?

I want to do this in C#.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This *can* be as simple as:

```
int index = list.IndexOf(b);
```

where `b` is the thing to find, **however** there is an ambiguity here over the definition of equality.  By default, classes will use reference-equality.  A common mistake is creating two class instances that have identical fields, and expecting them to count as *equal*.  To do this, you should really override `Equals` (and ideally implement `IEquatable<T>` for the same `T`).  If you override `Equals`, you should also override `GetHashCode`, and *ideally* the `==` and `!=` operators.

Another alternative is to find the match with a predicate or comparer, which can avoid all that work

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you have 4 elements like A,B,C,D.

```
      List<string> Char = new List<string>();
      Char.Add("A");
      Char.Add("B");
      Char.Add("C");
      Char.Add("D");
      int index = Char.IndexOf("B");
```

So the output will be 1. (index of B)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

[List(of T).IndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx)

Comment: Small side note: Since the question is tagged `C#`, it should better read [`List<T>.IndexOf(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Try this
Suppose your list's name is objList; Then

```
int index = objList.IndexOf("B");
```

Comment: he provide -1 but i need the index like 0 for a 1 for B 2 for C and 3 for D. are you know that.

Answer (score 0):

Things get a little complicated when you have a list of complex types. You need to know that your list can have multiple objects with the same parameters, eg. there can be few "A" on the list. It all comes down to querying the list.

I often use, eg.

```
var results = (from i in people
               where i.name == "Alexander" //here you put your predicate
               select myList.indexOf(i));
```

or

```
var results = people.Where(p=>p.name == "Alexander"); //this gives You full objects, not indices
```

That way I have list of indices of all the people with name "Alexander". You can loop through it, get a single one or whatever.

Just remember that list can have multiple indices of the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Some GREAT answers here esp @Marc Gravell I am expanding on the answers with
hypothetical but practical designs. We all put data in Databases and need to
retrieve that data and display it my favorite is a DataGridView that I can 
click on and retrieve my data. One caveat for this to work it would be best if
the ID is displayed in the DGV. How to display the data based on the index of ID
Enjoy the Code.

```
    private void btnSL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string str in vs)
        {
            var value = vs.Contains(udID.ToString());
            // value is bool USE to test for MATCH
            textBox1.Text = "var " + value + "";
            if(value == true)
            {
                int index = vs.IndexOf(udID.ToString());
                tbMessage.Text = vs[index] + " " + vs[index + 1] + " " + vs[index + 2];
            }
            else
            {
                tbMessage.Text = "That is NOT in the List vs";
            }
        }
    }
```